# How to create reference tables using fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, fluent-nhibernate

How can i create a 3 table schema from the following model classes.

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public IList<Photo> Photos {get; set;}
}

public class Photo
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Path {get; set;}
}
```

I want to create the following table structure in the database:

```
Product
-------
Id
Name

ProductPhotos
-------------
ProductId (FK Products.Id)
PhotoId (FK Photos.Id)

Photos
------
Id
Path
```

How i can express the above Database Schema using Fluent NHibernate?  I could only manage the following the Mapping but this does not get me the 3rd Photo ref table.

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {  
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);            
            Table("Products");
            HasMany(x => x.Photos).Table("ProductPhotos").KeyColumn("ProductId");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a classmap for the photo entity as well.

Comment: Tried this suggestion but no good.  Could you advise further of what the mapping details are?

Comment: public class PhotoMap : ClassMap<Photo>
{
   Id(x => x.Id);
   Map(x => x.Path);
}

You might need to specify the collection type (bag or list) and cascade as well in the hasmany in the product map. Citymap is a typo?

Comment: Do i need to create a 3rd ClassMap called ProductPhotoMap?  Your suggestion does not seem to work

Comment: No you don't have to create a 3th classmap. When it doesn't work, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: You need a `HasManyToMany` to specify that a join table should be used.